# Overhead when using keyword this?

Tags: asp.net, this

The scope of my question is solely ASP.NET, as the answer may be different for Java and any other C based language.

How much overhead is involved when using the keyword "this" within a class to dereference a property? It seems that I've seen certain sources try to discourage the use of "this" for dereferencing, but generaly I've just ignored them until now.

Comment: Sorry for the dupe post. I tried firstly to find a question that was similar to mind, but the search didn't bring back anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just a style issue.  As stated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352720/is-it-true-that-using-this-before-the-parameters-in-c-uses-more-memory), the compiler injects 'this' into implicit uses of this.  I would use it for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It supplied me with what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) recommended using this for all instance field reference.

And when compared to access the said field through a property, shouldn't it actually be faster (albeit unnoticable) by bypassing abstraction?

Answer (score 0):

No overhead.