# Pros and Cons of using this keyword in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, this

In programming you can use the this keyword

```
this.Textbox
```

or just

```
Textbox
```

What is the best practice?

Some benefits I can see is that using this makes it easier to see in intellisense and makes it easier to understand that it is a property.

Currently I don't use this... I read in some article somewhere that the guy removed all the references, but I don't remember why.

What are the pros and cons of using the this keyword?

Comment: The answers here are relevant as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105386/overhead-when-using-keyword-this

Comment: This is a pros vs cons question not a how to.  It is not a duplicate.

Comment: The title is bad but it is not a duplicate of the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `this` systematically will mean that you don't fall into a trap of referring to a local variable when in fact you want a member of `this`.

The downside: using `this` will make your code more verbose.

It's really up to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

The only cons are that it is more typing.  Using `this` (esp. consistently) also precludes, for example, using a parameter when you meant to use a property, e.g. a method `f(Textbox textbox) => {textbox = textbox}` when you meant to say `this.Textbox = textbox.`  Using it consistently not only makes it impossible to do so but also makes it stand out when you possibly could have.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer leaving out `this.` because it's less typing and less clutter and only use it when necessary because the identifier would be ambiguous otherwise.

As a sidenote I like the way member acces is handled in Cobra. It requires them to be prefixed with a `.` (or `_` for privates). So you'd use `.member=parameter`. And the first is obviously a member and the second a local variable. An elegant way to remove the ambiguity without becoming verbose.

Comment: Why?  our entire development team (including me) leaves it out as well.  This was never enforced as a coding standard it just happened.  Maybe due to the use of the underscore _privatemember

Comment: Lazyness. And since I use prefixed private members too the danger of mixing parameters and members is avoided too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference, really. Sometimes you have to use the `this` keyword, in cases like this:

```
private string Foo;
public void Bar(string Foo)
{
    this.Foo = Foo;
}
```

Not having the `this` will result in a bug where the parameter just sets itself to itself. It's less verbose, but some may say it's also less clear (hence preference).

Comment: Parameter ambiguity like this is just asking for trouble.  Style guidelines for .NET suggest camelCase for parameters.

Comment: I agree, I wasn't endorsing it - just pointing out that there are cases where it's actually needed, not just a style preference.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started to remove this. qualification from a codebase which has turned up a consequence:

Extension methods *must* have a this. prefix!

Thus, use of extension methods isn't transparent unless this. qualification is used generally.